# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended: java

Tags: java, jdbc, ora-00933

I am taking domains from a text file and passing it to a query one by one.
for first time the query is executing fine .. but when it takes the second domain and passing it to query getting error "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"
 Below is the code

```
sql.append("select person_org_id,profile_type_id as NEXUS, profile_option_id,profile_option_value  from TABLE1 ");
            sql.append(" where profile_type_id=1 and person_org_id in (select person_org_id from TABLE2 where ");
            sql.append(" account_id in (select account_id from TABLE3 where prod_id=10001 and prod_inst_name = ?)) ");

            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
            System.out.println("----------checkpoint -----------");

            ps.setString(1,domain_name);
            System.out.println("----------checkpoint 4-----------");
            rs= ps.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("----------checkpoint 5-----------");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this code in a loop, and you do not clear the StringBuilder or use a new one, then   the second time around, you will have the SQL statement twice and that would explain the error.

Why use a StringBuilder at all if a simple String would do? There is no variation in the SQL statement at all. Of course, this may have been a simplified example.

Also, if you do this in a loop, and the SQL is indeed the exact same one every time, you could just prepare the statement once, and execute it repeatedly in the loop. That is kind of what *prepared* statements are for.

Comment: thank you so much.. I have placed the sql outside the loop .. and execute it repeatedly in the loop its working... thanks  u soo much. But i am writing the data retrievied to an xls file and its writing twice...  checking that one...

Comment: Hey data is writing correctly in xls file... once again thanks alot for your answer.....